# C code completion in CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks

I am working on a C project on CodeBlocks,
but I still have C++ results when using the autocompletion.

Do you know how to keep only the C completion?

Answer (score 0):

In Settings>Editor>Code Completion the C/C++ parser options, allow you to alter the header files and extensions to parse.

Have you tried removing the C++ stuff?

Comment: when I delete the c++ headers from the field, and reload CodeBlocks   (close and open again), the headers come back.

Comment: I've tried it and happened to me to, but NOT on the (adv) page, where you choose what header & c files are parsed.  Strange, strange...